# Create new DIV using Javascript according to Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I convert this into Javascript? I'm trying to create more than 1 div of the same class but different images.

```
<div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(image/test1.jpg)"></div>
<div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(image/test2.jpg)"></div>
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'swiper-slide';

div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image/test1.jpg")';
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image/test2.jpg")';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
document.append(div)
```

Where 'document' can be any parent element.

Comment: This is correct. Everything else done by asker is correct.

Comment: Okay I'm so sorry. Probably my head was too tired that I missed this simple code.

Comment: Sorry about it, what I'm trying to achieve is How do I display multiple divs of different images. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this for multiple images 
make the image names into array and loop it

```js
var images = ['test1','test2','test3'];
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'swiper-slide';

div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("image/'+images[i]+'.jpg")';
div.innerHTML="asd"+i;
document.getElementById('asd').append(div);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="asd">
</body>
```